# EF - Best way to manage DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I know there are alot of articles regarding this topic, but wherever I looked, it was either too complicated or unclear to me.

My team develops web application that uses Entity framework code first. We also use Autofac for dependency injection.

Currently, the data access looks as follows:

The API supplied to projects that do not contain EF:

```
public class DataService
{
   private IDbContextFactory<MyContext> _factory;
   private IDataServiceExecutor _dataServiceExecutor;

   public DataService(IDbContextFactory<MyContext> factory, IDataServiceExecutor executor)
   {
       _factory = factory;
       _dataServiceExecutor = executor;
   }

   public void AddItem(Product prod)
   {
       using (var context = _factory.Create())
       {
           if (_dataServiceExecutor.AddItem(context, prod))
               context.SaveChanges();
       }
   }
}
```

My DataServiceExecutor:

```
public class DataServiceExecutor
{
    private IRepository<Product> _products;

    public DataService(IRepository<Product> products...more repositories)
    {
       _products = products;
    }

    public bool AddItem(DbContext context, Prouduct prod)
    {
        try
        {
            _products.AddItem(context, prod);

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             Log(..)
             return false;
        }
    }
}
```

All my repositories inherit from this abstract repository:

```
public abstract class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public void AddItem<T>(DbContext context, T item)
    {
        context.Set<T>().Add(item);
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

The good thing is that a context is used per transaction this way.

The bad thing is that both my service methods and my repositories methods take context directly. The application is not so big, so for now the method injection of the context is fine, but it will probably become bigger and so the context injection at it's current state is problematic in my opinion. And it looks bad.

Maybe there are more pros and cons which I'm not aware of..

Is there any way I'm not familiar with to make data access better?

Comment: You might have better luck asking this over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes like `DataServiceExecutor` (essentially a verb) always spell design flaws. It's a method (`Execute...`) disguised as a class. Responsibilities of such classes aren't clear because their functions inevitably belong to other classes.

The problem with an in itself great pattern like Inversion of Control is that an IoC container can be used to inject *any* dependency. So they allow you to create a tangle of dependencies and scattered responsibilities and still do a decent job managing life cycles. They may obscure life cycle problems you'd have otherwise.

**So let's ignore IoC for a moment** and see what your code would look like with simple object creation if you call `DataServiceExecutor.AddItem`.

```
var product = new Product();
var factory = new DbContextFactory<MyContext>(); // Dependencies unknown
var productRepository = new Repository<Product>(context);
var executor = new DataServiceExecutor(productRepository);
var dataService = new DataService(factory, executor);
```

Inside `dataServiceAddItem` method you essentially have:

```
using (var context = _factory.Create())
{
    executor.AddItem(context, product);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If `DataService` would receive the `productRepository` instead of the `executor` this would boil down to:

```
productRepository.AddItem(context, product);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The `executor` can be taken out easily. Its only role seems to be error logging. But that could be done by `DataService` just as well.

But we're not done yet. As you indicated yourself, these methods taking a context as parameter are a bit awkward. But now `DataServiceExecutor` is out of the picture, it's far more natural to do:

```
var product = new Product();
var factory = new DbContextFactory<MyContext>();
using (var context = _factory.Create())
{
    var productRepository = new Repository<Product>(context);
    productRepository.AddItem(product);

    // And for example
    var orderRepository = new Repository<Order>(context);
    orderRepository.AddItem(order);

    // One SaveChanges call!
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And the `DataService` is gone too.

Now `EFRepository` stores its `context` as a member variable, and `AddItem` looks like this:

```
public void AddItem<T>(T item)
{
    _context.Set<T>().Add(item);
}
```

**And now back to IoC.**

In the light of IoC, the main problem of your code is this inside `DataService.AddItem`:

```
using (var context = _factory.Create())
```

You create a context that is not managed by the IoC container. It's lifespan is scoped to the `AddItem` method. Therefore you have to pass it around all over the place to make sure everything within the business transaction uses this one instance. By bringing the repository's dependency (to a context) back to constructor injection, it's much easier to let the IoC container manage the context's lifespan.

By the way, you say that `DataService` is part of "the API supplied to projects that do not contain EF". But it does refer to `MyContext` in its generic parameter. Maybe `MyContext` is an abstraction too, I don't know. Anyhow, you could supply instances of this abstraction by IoC as well.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! First of all the service indeed supplies the API, Autofac injects context factory in it's ctor. Second, the purpose of the executor was to actually do the actions, the service responsibility was to either save changes if action succeeded and/or dispose context. I do know it's ugly to pass the context, yet don't know how to use dependency injection to prevent it and yet keep same context be used for each transaction, I couldn't understand from your answer how to inject it either

Comment: You can inject it similarly to how you inject the factory etc. I.e. by constructor injection. I'm sure there are many examples of how to inject contexts with Autofac. But it would probably change a lot in your program flow. I think that's the greatest problem. But what I showed you is a much more common (and versatile) way to work with repositories and contexts.

Comment: I read again your first comment and everything was so right, getting rid of the executor is smart, as well as taking dependencies of repositories and take context in its ctor. Now I face another big problem which is how to actually register dbContext object in my startApp.. It forces me to refernece Ef which I really don't like

Comment: I don't know AutoFac hands-on, but in Castle Windsor it's possible to create "installers" in another assembly that register internal types into the container. The IoC container auto-discovers the installer classes. Maybe with AutoFac a similar approach can be achieved.

Comment: But it'll force me to reference Autofac from my Data project, which is the same problem, won't it?

Comment: Yeah, there must be some place where both are known simultaneously.

Comment: Than which is better? Handle context creation alone? Or reference a dll I might decide to replace later on?

Comment: Hard to decide. I decided to reference Castle Windsor in the assembly using EF. If I take another IoC container, there's not much code to be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

My opion is that the solution is not correctly layered. I guess the DataService is the top layer that is accessed from the outside world?

In that case i would change to the following:

- The service gets the repository (or datalayer) injected through the constructor (and then properly disposed). The service methods then only need relevant parameters.
- What is the datalayer used for? Can it be removed? I normally have a datalayer below the services that holds all repositories. In that case the datalayer could be responsible for disposing all repositories when the service disposes the data layer.
- The repository could be kept as is but should have the context injected through the constructor.

Comment: Upadated my question to make it clearer. If you could describe your answer with pieces of code maybe I'd understand better